# How do you write an amulet

Tags: how-to, health-safety-shmira, practical-kabbalah

The internet has many examples of Jewish amulets. I would like to know how, step by step, amulet is written. I understand there may be different formula for different amulets but I assume the general process is the same, with just the content changing. If this assumption is incorrect, please provide an example of how to write an amulet to aid with health.

Comment: 1 Write "pray for health and do Mitzvot and stop playing around with magic tricks" on a piece of paper. 2 Read it. 3 Roll it up and place it in the nearest trash can. (Substitute "health" for other things as needed.)

Comment: No one who knows the answer to this question  is giving it online

Comment: http://www.wslibrary.net/sifria/en/segulot/2373-_400-.html , have fun

Comment: Before dealing with this art, please read  Bavli Shabat 115:2.

Comment: Also, Rambam, rules of idolatry 11:12.

Comment: @doubleaa recycling bin

Comment: @heshy trash can!!

Comment: @sam Pesachim 4:9 :)

Comment: i expected this question to get this type of response, but wanted to give the benefit of the doubt. sad.

Comment: @rikki what's sad?

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Feinstein [(Igros Moshe YD 2:141:3)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=237&hilite=) discusses the possibility of using the parsha of Krias Shema used for the Mezuza as a protective amulet. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHmGpXqlj54) video shows how to write the parshiyos of a mezuza - not that Rav Moshe suggests you should do so, but that it would serve as an amulet.